# Graphics freeze

Tags: graphics, 22.04, freeze, amdgpu

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 and recently have been having a lot of issues around the graphics freezing

When the graphics freeze, inputs such as the keyboard work, I can switch to another terminal (Ctrl+alt+few for example), login and interact with the system there

I notice in the terminal a lot of messages like this

```
[drm:amdgpu_cs_ioctl [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to initialize parser -125!
```

It seems that the graphics just freeze

Two questions...

Is there a way to recover my gui session when this happens?

What's causing this?  Any troubleshooting ideas would be great

Comment: Still trying to figure this out, I also have the issue in the pre release 22.10 with the latest kernel.  I'm using oibaf drivers.  Any suggestions on what might cause this kind of issue? Not sure if it's hardware, drivers, kernel, software or something else.

Comment: Still unsure of the cause but noticed that the latest time it failed, it automatically recovered the graphical session (although I lost my open windows, the graphical session was a new one)